# WAMP - Unable to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

my operating system is windows 7, 32 bits. I downloaded wampserver (32 BITS & PHP 5.4.7 )

After I installed the WAMMP, I made the following changes to my hostname, dbuser and dbpassword to the "testmysql.php" in notepad :

```
    <?php 
    $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','Enter the password for root or leave   blank  if you have not yet set a password');

    if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
     echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($link); 
   ?>
```

I got the following error message when I tried to save the file, saying:

> Warning:  Access denied

My question is what am I doing wrong and why am I receiving this message?

Comment: If this is your exact code you get 'access denied' because the password you sent is "Enter the password....". You have to provide an empty string if you did not set a password, like it says...

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Is it the correct username and password? Is the DB server running? Is the server actually located at 127.0.0.1?

Comment: try connecting to localhost

Comment: First turn your php errors on by doing this. 
 ini_set('display', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL); I would advice you to use mysqli_connect, because mysql extension is deprecated meaning it will no longer be available in the future php versions. see here   http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: thanks for your swift reply all. but so far no luck, I still get the same error message: _Access Denied_.

Comment: ajtrichards reply codezilla: I do have access to the server, I have now changed the username to 'local host' and password to 'root'. The DB is running. but thanks for your suggestions. I still get the same response. still not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wait... I just reread your question and you wrote that you get an error message when you tried to save the file. Is that correct? Because then it has nothing do to with what is inside the file, it will be a file permissions issue. Or do you get the error when executing the script (which we all assume)?

Comment: I get the error when I try and save the testmysql.php file that connects to the server, so if I add the following path to my browser: http://localhost/testmysql.php I receive the following error - Object not found!. I decided to re-install the server onto my local system but received the a different response:-
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Thanks to those at stackoverflow who helped tried to solve this MySql Problem with me. It's finally been solved...the problem was in Wins 7 permissions...they were not activated. Once permissions were allowed I can now connect the testmysql.php file to MySql.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
    $link = mysql_connect('locahost','root','');
    if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
     echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply PravinS. I have made the changes that you have suggested in your last comment, however it has not done the trick I'm afraid to say. A little more patience?

Comment: Besides creating an empty string as placeholder for my dbpassword, replacing dbuser with 'root' and the host name with 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' would there be any other alternative to correct this problem, as i guessing there is obviously something I have overlooked..?